# Why do the 2-star items have a "1" next to them?

Tags: spiral-knights

Here's a clipping of the shop list from the gun shop in Haven bazaar.

[image]

Why do all the 2-star and better weapons have a `1` on them (as highlighted in the image above)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the number of the item that the vendor has in stock and available to you.

Most vendors are randomized per/player. There is no restocking, the limited quantities only affect *you*, though it is possible for the randomized offerings to be similar, or even identical on a day-to-day basis. Stocks from the vendors in town reset and randomize every day at midnight server time.

The exception to this is the traveling merchant, Basil, available on the "Clockwork Terminal". These offerings are the same *per party*, but again, quantities exist separately for each player. There's no need to "rush" over to get the best recipes - if Basil offers it to one player, he offers it to *all* players.

The further exception is that if a player *joins* the party on a clockwork terminal level or the level before, the quantity of all available recipes is set to 0. This is to prevent someone getting a potentially valuable recipe without investing any energy (since it costs 0 energy to join on a clockwork terminal level or take the elevator down to the terminal) into a dungeon.

Comment: Hope you don't mind me tweaking your answer, but while your info is very helpful and it didn't address my core question, and I wanted to accept the extra info. :) Please feel free to re-tweak if you feel it necessary.

Answer (score 4):

That's the number of them the vendor has in stock.  You see it on recipe vendors as well.

For most vendors, I believe they restock almost immediately... it's the in-dungeon vendors it makes a difference on.

Comment: It's so obvious that is almost *hurts* that I didn't realise. *facepalm* Thanks and +1, however Raven's answer contains other bits of info that are pretty useful, so I've tweaked his answer slightly and given him the tick.